# Not showing error messages when validated using @valid(JSR-303) in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I have specified  `<mvc:annotation-driven  />` in dispatcher-servlet. 
I am not using @InitBinder.
And I am using @valid annotation for validation in controller's method like

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "new")
    public String save(@Valid Article article,ModelMap model) {
//code here
}
```

And validation works fine, but instead of showing error in .. 
sample shown in html code

```
<tr>
         <td>Title</td>
         <td><form:input path="title"/></td>
         <td><form:errors path="title"/></td>
</tr>
```

It throws exception like..

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException:
>   Request processing failed; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.validation.BindException:
>   org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult:
>   2 errors Field error in object
>   'article' on field 'urlInfo.url':
>   rejected value []; codes
>   [typeMismatch.article.urlInfo.url,typeMismatch.urlInfo.url,typeMismatch.url,typeMismatch.java.net.URL,typeMismatch];
>   arguments
>   [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
>   codes
>   [article.urlInfo.url,urlInfo.url];
>   arguments []; default message
>   [urlInfo.url]]; default message
>   [Failed to convert property value of
>   type 'java.lang.String' to required
>   type 'java.net.URL' for property
>   'urlInfo.url'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException:
>   Unable to convert value  from type
>   'java.lang.String' to type
>   'java.net.URL'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException:
>   Unable to convert value  from type
>   'java.lang.String' to type
>   'java.net.URL'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException]
>   Field error in object 'article' on
>   field 'title': rejected value [];
>   codes
>   [Size.article.title,Size.title,Size.java.lang.String,Size];
>   arguments
>   [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
>   codes [article.title,title]; arguments
>   []; default message
>   [title],{javax.validation.constraints.Size.message},6,[Ljava.lang.Class;@1db3aac,2147483647,[Ljava.lang.Class;@1e90abf];
>   default message [size must be between
>   6 and 2147483647]

```
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:659)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:563)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:390)
 org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:213)
 org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:171)
 org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
 org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
 org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:381)
 org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:390)
```

How to configure it, to not throw an exception and instead return to page and show error messages...

Comment: How have you enabled the validation? Using `@InitBinder` on your controller, or `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` in your context? Whichever one you're using, please add those bits to your question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should explicitly decide what to do with validation errors:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "new") 
public String save(@Valid Article article, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) { 
    if (result.hasErrors())
        return "formView";
```

Answer (score 18):

In your controller handler method, make sure that the BindingResult argument is immediately after the command argument.

Comment: Very strange but this worked for me as well. I had always been told that Spring can figure out controller method parameters on its own and I would never need to worry about them! But this is at the least one instance where the order of the parameters impacts the execution!

Comment: Yes, the BindingResult has to be placed exactly after the input(request) attribute. Worked for me as well.